# jQuery nextAll() traversing method equivalent in Nokogiri?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, nokogiri, jquery-traversing

I wrote the following code with jQuery:

```
$("#bar").nextAll(".foo").each(function(index){
    console.log($(this))
})
```

And I'd like to transpose it to **Nokogiri**.

I read the [documentation for Nokogiri - jQuery](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/From-jQuery-Traversing) but I cannot find how to write an equivalent of the [nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) method.

Any idea?

Comment: there is nothing in the docs also.

Comment: @Jai yes, exactly... :|